# Why is Java's Semaphore fairness an argument to the constructor rather than the acquire() / tryAcquire() calls?

Tags: java, semaphore

I see absolutely no reason why this is not a per-call option. The semaphore may be downed in different code paths (master checking progress / workers grabbing work from queue / ...) with different fairness requirements. Perhaps in one case we want to check progress fairly, while in the other we want the same few workers working if there is only enough work for the running workers, to optimize L1 cache hits etc.)

Comment: I don't understand the question. Thread 1 asked for fairness and got it (meaning going to the OS to sleep and contending like other waiters to get the lock). Thread 2 didn't get the lock because he was willing to grab the lock without sleeping even if there are waiters that will never win the race if he keeps letting go and grabbing in a tight loop. The meaning of fairness is lining up if there are waiters, nothing else. Don't confuse it with Websters' definition. It is irrelevant to this context.

Comment: I say the semantics are improper. You say read the documentation. There is no reason to force every thread to line up if we want any to line up. Therefore, it is an arbitrary limitation. If the programmer wants it your way, he can make all calls fair. You yet have to show one reason why he MUST be uniform. As for FIFO, you have no control on it. The OS will decide who gets woken. You simply choose to go to OS to sleep, and how many it should wake. You can hope for a FIFO. But unless you can show me where in Linux (man 7 futex OR man 2 futex) it says FIFO, Java cannot guarantee that either.

Comment: It has everything to do with futex on linux as it is the only way to get preemptive multitasking offered by the OS. If you don't believe me, create locking contention in a tight loop and strace to see the system calls into the OS by Java in the contended case. As for me creating "my own", semantics should create restrictions only when they make sense. Can you name a single reason why this restriction exists? Why can I not specify this argument per call? That is the only thing at issue, and as I expected before posting, no one was able to produce a single good reason why.

Comment: BTW, if you actually want to try strace'ing it, remember that to get the system calls from the child threads, you need strace -f

Answer (score 1):

`tryAcquire` is non-fair even if you have set `fair` to true in the constructor.

> Even when this semaphore has been set to use a fair ordering policy, a
>   call to `tryAcquire()` will immediately acquire a permit if one
>   is available, whether or not other threads are currently waiting. This
>   "barging" behavior can be useful in certain circumstances, even though
>   it breaks fairness. If you want to honor the fairness setting, then
>   use `tryAcquire(long, TimeUnit) tryAcquire(0, TimeUnit.SECONDS)`
>   which is almost equivalent (it also detects interruption).

-- https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Semaphore.html#tryAcquire()

---

I think this behavior would be sufficient to enable the scenario you outlined (checking progress vs. grabbing work).

Comment: Thanks. But I see these as 2 different things. In a sane implementation, tryAcquire() should only be different from acquire() in that it returns failed instead of going to sleep. Fairness has to do with whether it gets the lock without sleep if there are waiters (a race). So fairness (if at all) comes into play first, and if it didn't get the lock in userland, _try_ makes it not sleep but fail. In other words, in a sane implementation, I should be able to:  while(sem.tryAcquire(fair)) { sem.grant(); } 

and never block myself, and not starve others. 

Cheers.